# Engine knock when engine is hot

Tags: engine, mazda, knock, mpv

I have an 05 Mazda MPV V6 engine. When it starts up there is no noise and everything is fine. After engine is hot I get a knocking sound and the oil pressure light comes on. By looking at earlier post it seems that I have a possible rod bearing going. Can you clarify if this is definitely a rod knock. With a stethoscope I only hear that noise on the Left Bank near the exhaust side camshaft and I do not hear it on the lower part of the engine.